# Kotlin Hibernate JPA Lazy fetch not working through the controller

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I've get a full sample application here: https://github.com/MrMojoR/hibernateOnKotlin

And this code is based on this blogpost: https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/

The problem is, that while lazy fetch works perfectly from the integration test, there is an Exception in debugger:
[Exception from test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltKWp.jpg)

When I run the same code from the Controller, there is no Exception, the whole entity is loaded:
[No Exception from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCrs.jpg)

**How is that possible?**
Thanks very much for your help!

I'll post the code snippets anyway:

AbstractJpaPersistable.kt

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
import org.springframework.data.util.ProxyUtils
import java.io.Serializable
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass
import javax.persistence.Transient

/**
 * Abstract base class for entities. Allows parameterization of id type, chooses auto-generation and implements
 * [equals] and [hashCode] based on that id.
 *
 * This class was inspired by [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable], which is part of the Spring Data project.
 */
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractJpaPersistable<T : Serializable> : Persistable<T> {

    companion object {
        private val serialVersionUID = -5554308939380869754L
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private var id: T? = null

    override fun getId(): T? {
        return id
    }

    /**
     * Must be [Transient] in order to ensure that no JPA provider complains because of a missing setter.
     *
     * @see org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable.isNew
     */
    @Transient
    override fun isNew() = null == getId()

    override fun toString() = "Entity of type ${this.javaClass.name} with id: $id"

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        other ?: return false

        if (this === other) return true

        if (javaClass != ProxyUtils.getUserClass(other)) return false

        other as AbstractJpaPersistable<*>

        return if (null == this.getId()) false else this.getId() == other.getId()
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return 31
    }
}
```

Person.kt:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.FetchType
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne
import javax.persistence.OneToMany    

@Entity
class Person(
        val name: String,
        @ManyToOne(cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        val street: Street
) : AbstractJpaPersistable<Long>()

@Entity
class Address(
        val zipCode: String,
        val city: String
) : AbstractJpaPersistable<Long>()

@Entity
class Street(
        @OneToMany(cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        val adresses: MutableSet<Address>
) : AbstractJpaPersistable<Long>()
```

PersonRepository:

```
import com.kotlinexpertise.hibernatedemo.model.Person
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface PersonRepository : JpaRepository<Person, Long>
```

PersonService:

```
import com.kotlinexpertise.hibernatedemo.model.Person
import com.kotlinexpertise.hibernatedemo.repository.PersonRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class PersonService(val personRepository: PersonRepository) {

    fun savePerson(person: Person) {
        personRepository.saveAndFlush(person)
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

[What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)

This property should be set to false:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

It is not a Kotlin issue, but a Spring issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy relies on the fact that it has active connection available.

Connections are managed by EntityManager in Hibernate.

But your debugger runs on a totally different thread, so it doesn't have access to EntityManager. Hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you've misunderstood me a bit. I think the exception should be the expected behaviour with lazy fetch enabled. So when the exception is not thrown lazy fetch is not working in my opinion.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that: (1) at runtime everything works fine (2) during test everything works fine (3) exception is thrown only by debugger?

Comment: Yes, and in the meantime I've figured out the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot Thanks very much anyway, your help directed me to the right direction